# chrome.tabs.executeScript Inside chrome.tabs.create

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

My chrome extension worked great untill lately, I think it is maybe related to new chrome extension policies or something.
I have a script, that runs on a website, opens some specifics links in new tabs, and should run a script inside those newly created tabs.
It has worked flawlessly untill now, now it doesn't.

Manifest:

```
  {
  "name": "Extension ",
  "version": "1.6.2",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "options_page": "options.html",
  "description": "Extension ",
  "permissions": [
    "<all_urls>", "tabs", "activeTab", "storage"
  ],
  "background": {
  "matches": [ "*://*.website.com/*" ],
  "scripts" : [ "thirdParty/jquery.js", "event.js" ],
  "persistent": false
  },
    "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [ "*://*.ebay.com/usr/*" ],
      "css": [ "ebayButton.css" ],
      "js": [ "ebayButton.js" ],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ]
}
```

The script starts by clicking the extension icon inside "*://*.website.com/*", the with the background script "event.js":

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(firstFunction);

scanOnLoad = true;

// This gets me the required URLS inside "://.website.com/*" - works
function firstFunction(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: 'firstFunction.js'}, results => {
        results[0].forEach(secondFunction);
    });
}

// This opens a new tab for each returned URL - works
function secondFunction(url) {
    chrome.tabs.create({url, pinned: true, active: false}, thirdFunction);
}

// This used to work, but now it doesn't. This function should execute 'thirdFunction.js'
// inside every opened tab. for some reason - now it doesn't work.
function thirdFunction(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id,{file: 'thirdFunction.js'}, results => {
        chrome.tabs.remove(tab.id);
        console.log(results[0]);
    });
}
```

'thirdFunction.js' does work and returns a list when trying to run the script on the website:

```
[...document.getElementsByClassName("mem_loc")]
    .filter(a => !(a.textContent.trim().endsWith('China') || a.textContent.trim().endsWith('Korea')))
    .map(a=> document.getElementsByClassName("analyze")[0].href.replace('search=true&',''))
```

It does create the tabs, it closes them either, but it doesn't get any results from 'thirdFunction.js' as it used to get before. There are no errors inside the created tabs, but there are two errors inside the background script ('event.js')
for each created tab. First error:

```
Error in response to tabs.executeScript: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at Object.chrome.tabs.executeScript.results [as callback] (chrome-extension://biknnfhbimcbgaefmocdaeaioabnbpkm/event.js:43:28)
    at Object.thirdFunction [as callback] (chrome-extension://biknnfhbimcbgaefmocdaeaioabnbpkm/event.js:41:17)
```

2nd error:

```
Unchecked runtime.lastError while running tabs.executeScript: The tab was closed.
    at Object.thirdFunction [as callback] (chrome-extension://biknnfhbimcbgaefmocdaeaioabnbpkm/event.js:41:17)
```

I think I have premissions to everything, because as I said it used to work untill now. I have no idea why it stopped working. Tried searching the web for answers, no answer solved my problem. Any help is appriciated :)

Comment: If the change occurred after updating Chrome, it might be caused by a bug in the browser. Try your extension in an older portable Chrome and in a newer Chrome Canary. Also, try removing `"activeTab"` because you don't need it (`"<all_urls>"` supersedes that).

Comment: It doesn't work on selenium chromedriver too, and on my browser. I haven't changed anything but it stopped working (only the 3rd function inside event.js) @wOxxOm

Comment: You've ignored my suggestion, I have no other ideas.

Comment: I've definitely never ignored your suggestion, you have solved all of my previous chrome extension probloem, I admire you! :)
removing `"activeTab"` didn't worked. I've installed Chrome v63 (previous verison) - it did solve it!. Now, if there is a problem with the current chrome verison (or they changed something in it), where do I see it / report it?. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You can report on https://crbug.com but make sure to attach (or link) the extension and easy-to-follow steps for reproduction of the problem.

Comment: Hi @AsafKfir, I encountered the same issue. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @RobHawkins yes, as i said - I've installed chrome previous verison and it worked :)